# app-debug.apk does not exist on disk

Tags: android, android-studio

I've looked through all tips in the other threads here, tried all proposed solutions (last thing I did was completely uninstall and reinstall Android Studio), and I still get it...

If I select "Build APK", then whenever I change the code the changes aren't put in effect in the new versions of the app... I think I'm going to give this up for the weekend...

First I had all the database errors I pointed to in the other thread (unsolved), then Android Studio started "ignoring" changes in my code (like commented lines being ran as they weren't commented), now invalidating the cache and everything else (including the reinstall) left me here...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which version you are using?

Comment: the latest, but I may have solved it by adding "gradle :app:build" in Gradle Aware-make under "Run/Debug configurations"...

Answer (score 12):

I sorted it myself (this question was asked multiple times around here, HOWEVER it WAS NOT satisfactorily answered):

Go to "Run" - "Edit Configurations", look at the "Before Launch" field at the bottom of the window, click on the "+" sign and add the "Gradle-aware Make" option to the list, no additional text needed on the next input window (just click on "ok").

Comment: I had to add this after upgrading to Android Studio 3.1 Beta. Thx, it helped me :-)